# How can I use xtick in tkz-euclide?

Tags: tkz-euclide

I want to use `xtick` and `ytick` in `tkz-euclide` but I can't the results. This is my code.

```
 \documentclass[border=2mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath}
\usetkzobj{all}
\tikzset{hidden/.style = {thick, dashed}}
\tkzSetUpPoint[fill=black,size=10]
 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmin=-8,xmax = 2,ymin=-6,ymax=4]
xtick={-7,-6,1},
ytick={-5,-4,2},
%\tkzAxeXY
\draw[->,ultra thick] (-8.5,0)--(3.5,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->,ultra thick] (0,-6.5)--(0,4.5) node[above]{$y$};
\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{-7/2/A,
-6/-5/B,
0/3/D,
1/-4/C,
-3/-1/T,
0/0/O}
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](C,B,T)
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](D)
\tkzLabelPoints[below=0.3cm,left](O)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black](A,B,C,D,T,O)
\tkzDrawCircle[ultra thick](T,A)
\tkzDrawPolygon[ultra thick](A,B,C,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I add `xtick` and `ytick`?
[image]

Comment: AFAIK `xtick` and `ytick` are only options of the `axes` environment. Maybe you can draw the ticks manuelly like `\foreach \x in {-7,-6,1}  \draw[ultra thick](\x,.15cm)--(\x,-.15cm)node[below]{$\x$};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used `\tkzPointShowCoord` in order add.

```
 \documentclass[border=2mm,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath}
\usetkzobj{all}
\tikzset{hidden/.style = {thick, dashed}}
\tkzSetUpPoint[fill=black,size=10]
 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmin=-9,xmax = 2,ymin=-7,ymax=4]
%\tkzAxeXY
\tkzDefPoints{-7/2/A,
-6/-5/B,
0/3/D,
1/-4/C,
-3/-1/T,
0/0/O}
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](C,B,T)
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](D)
\tkzLabelPoints[below=0.3cm,left](O)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=black](A,B,C,D,T,O)
\tkzDrawCircle[ultra thick](T,A)
\tkzDrawPolygon[ultra thick](A,B,C,D)
\tkzDrawX[ultra thick,noticks]
\tkzDrawY[ultra thick,noticks]
\tkzPointShowCoord[ultra thick,xlabel=$-7$,ylabel=$2$,xstyle={below=6pt},ystyle={right=6pt}](A)
\tkzPointShowCoord[ultra thick,xlabel=$-6$,ylabel=$-5$,xstyle={above=6pt},ystyle={right=0.2cm}](B)
\tkzPointShowCoord[ultra thick,xlabel=$1$,ylabel=$-4$,xstyle={above=6pt},ystyle={left=0.2}](C)
\tkzGrid
\tkzMarkRightAngle[thick,size=0.3](A,B,C)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[thick,size=0.3](B,C,D)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[thick,size=0.3](C,D,A)
\tkzMarkRightAngle[thick,size=0.3](D,A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]